# all enabled to true and keyword token analyzer does not return any results

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using keyword token analyzer in my elastic search given below

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "default" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My order mapping is here

```
{
    "order": {
        "_all": {"enabled" : true},
        "properties": {
            "OrderData": {
                "properties": {
                    "BusinessRuleData": {
.........
}
```

So now when I querying using the following json

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "_all",
            "query": "SomeText"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I dont get any results for this. Where as if I change my analyzer to "standard" then _all search works fine.  Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: The changes I made it  work is using custom analyzer with tokenizer as "standard" and define that analyzer for _all field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its probably indexed as whole. I think we have to search whole document which does not make sense. So the point is we have to use standard tokenizer for _all indexing.